# ssh -vvvT failing with "shell request failed on channel 0"

Tags: git, ssh

While trying to setup git SSH from my windows laptop, I see the below.  How do I make it work? Currently, I see "shell request failed on channel 0"

Command Example:

```
ssh -vvvT git@<server> -p 7999
Sharing last few lines of the output below
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]  
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0  
debug2: channel 0: send open  
debug3: send packet: type 90  
debug1: Entering interactive session.  
debug1: pledge: network  
debug3: receive packet: type 91  
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback start  
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY  
debug3: ssh_packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x20  
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0  
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1  
debug3: send packet: type 98  
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done  
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 2097152 rmax 32768  
debug3: receive packet: type 100  
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 100 id 0  
shell request failed on channel 0
```

***shell request failed on channel 0***

Thank you

Comment: The problem is not at your end, but rather at the server `<server>`. You should check *its* sshd logs to see what the problem is there.

Comment: Sure torek.  Thank you.

Comment: On a side note, curious as why the below failed. Thought, it was related to the above.  



$ git fetch --tags --force --progress -- ssh://git@<server>:7999/<pathToGITFile> +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*  
git: '7999' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.  
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.  



Please make sure you have the correct access rights  
and the repository exists.

Comment: That doesn't look right: `ssh://git@host:port/path` should be fine.

Comment: Sorry see the same error always for the 3 variants as below


$ git fetch --tags --force --progress ssh://git@host:port/path +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*


$ git fetch  ssh://git@host:port/path +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*


$ git fetch  ssh://git@host:port/path

Answer (score 3):

Since it depends on the server, you need to check if said server does listen on port 7999 for SSH connection.
7999 seems to be the [standard SSH port for a BitBucket server](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/which-ports-does-bitbucket-server-listen-on-and-what-are-they-used-for-806029586.html), so check that hosting service log.

And you can use `ssh -vvvT git@<server> -p 7999 /bin/bash -i` to see if it generates any additional information.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the command as administrator :-)

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem only with one user. The others could login. In this case just restarting the server solved the problem.